# can Prometheus store basic auth passwords in any format other then plain text?

Tags: prometheus

in order to access scraping endpoints with basic auth in Prometheus, I need to put my password in plain text in the Prometheus config file. Is there a way to store these password in some other manner? using environment variables for example
I would prefer not to keep my passwords in just plain text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's the only supported way. There are no plans to add other ways.